# What is the purpose & advantage of spring specifications

Tags: spring

I would like to know why we are using spring jpa specifications in spring boot application. I could see something like specifications (classname).and , .or these kind of operations what exactly it is?

Answer (score 1):

Spring JPA specifications allow you to define a predicate (a part of WHERE clause of a query).

This helps you create complex queries in an object oriented style, allow you to create reusable predicates that you may use in different queries without repeating yourself, and it can help you create dynamic queries that can be constructed at runtime.

One example of a good use case for specifications is a search page with optional filtering criteria (think any eCommerce website). Using JPA specifications you can define a predicate for each filter and at runtime you can include in your query only the predicates that are related to the filters that the user has applied.